# 'Error retrieving information from server' while downloading app from Google Play

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-tab

I recently reset my Samsung Galaxy Tab plus which runs on Android 3.2. I then tried to set up my tablet again by downloading applications, but it shows that there was error retrieving information.

[image: Screenshot_of_error_message]

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with the Play Store. Give it a few hours and try again.

It should eventually come good. :)

Comment: What is the common problem?  Time does not appear to be fixing this as it's been over 24 hours...